# What's the best way to store an ArrayList between activities, and save to internal storage on exiting app

Tags: android, performance, android-database

I've been developing an Android catalogue app for a flooring store and wish to implement a persistent cart feature. The hierarchy of activities is as follows:

- Activity 1: Choose the category of product (carpet, timber, etc.)
- Activity 2: Shows list of products in the selected category
- Activity 3: Shows more info and colors for the selected product

Within activity 3 I would like to have a button for adding the product to a "cart". This would be very rudimentary data: product name, color, image URL. Then on all 3 activities, I wish to implement a button that reveals a fragment containing all items that have been added to cart. When the app closes this list of items should be stored locally and repopulate the fragment when the app is reopened next. However, while the app is still running, is storing locally and reading in the list every time the user changes between activities an acceptable/ efficient solution? Is there a better solution that involves keeping the list in memory/ passing it between activities?

Comment: As convention you should use SQlite but It depend on situation if there is only one user and cart will have only few items like 10-50 it will be better to use Shared Preference , but if there are multiple user and you want old user cart detail on login agin you should use sqlite .

Comment: To clarify, the intended use is a single user with few items. Is it inefficient to read from Shared Preference each time an activity changes?

Comment: As you described in question , You need to save that item in Activity 3 so you don't need to access shared preference in each time you just need pass data from one activity to another .